# Does a scout get the bonus from aspect of the lurking spider on both attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranger

The scout stance "[Aspect of the Lurking Spider](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13593)" gives a +2 damage bonus when you have combat advantage.

> While you have combat advantage against an enemy, you gain a +2 power bonus to damage rolls against it.

Does this apply to both your melee basic attack and your dual weapon attack if you have combat advantage for both attacks (Say from flanking?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, the scout gets the damage bonus on all attacks**

The power reads "While you have combat advantage against an enemy, you gain a +2 power bonus to damage rolls against it."

So as long as you have combat advantage you get the bonus.

You don't add the bonus to each die rolled during a roll, but rather to the total damage roll (which could be 2d4 from your weapon, and another 2d6 from your sneak attack, or a flat number + a few d6 for rolling a crit with a magic weapon)

Additionally, there must actually be a damage roll - so powers that deal fixed damage don't get the bonus, however critical hits which "do damage as if the maximum result had been rolled" get the bonus due to the "had been rolled" clause.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, definitely.** Take a literal reading: it says that, while you have combat advantage against an enemy, you get a +2 power bonus to damage rolls against it. This means *all* of the damage rolls. If you take this stance and additionally somehow have the Ranger daily to make five attacks, all five of them will get the +2 to damage.

Note that it doesn't count towards damage that didn't involve dice. You don't have to have actually rolled them - you get it for critical hits, for example, even without a magic weapon or High Crit - but dice must have been involved.

**EDIT:** In general, you can read pretty much any rule, power, ability, feat, or whatnot in 4e as literally as possible and get it right. The handful of real controversies tend to stem from places where things are not well-defined (or perceived as such).